# Create New Empty Word Document

Tags: c#, openxml, openxml-sdk

I'm trying to create an empty Word document (DOCX) using OpenXML SDK 2.5. The following code is not working for me because MainDocumentPart is null.

```
    public static void CreateEmptyDocxFile(string fileName, bool overrideExistingFile)
    {
        if (System.IO.File.Exists(fileName))
        {
            if (!overrideExistingFile)
                return;
            else
                System.IO.File.Delete(fileName);
        }

        using (WordprocessingDocument document = WordprocessingDocument.Create(fileName, WordprocessingDocumentType.Document))
        {
            const string docXml =
         @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""UTF-8"" standalone=""yes""?> 
            <w:document xmlns:w=""http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main"">
                <w:body>
                    <w:p>
                        <w:r>
                            <w:t></w:t>
                        </w:r>
                    </w:p>
                </w:body>
            </w:document>";

            using (Stream stream = document.MainDocumentPart.GetStream())
            {
                byte[] buf = (new UTF8Encoding()).GetBytes(docXml);
                stream.Write(buf, 0, buf.Length);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It is much easier to use OpenXML classes then writing xml string. Try this:

```
using (WordprocessingDocument document = WordprocessingDocument.Create(fileName, WordprocessingDocumentType.Document))
{
    MainDocumentPart mainPart = document.AddMainDocumentPart();
    mainPart.Document = new Document(new Body());
    //... add your p, t, etc using mainPart.Document.Body.AppendChild(...);

    //seems like there is no need in this call as it is a creation process
    //document.MainDocumentPart.Document.Save();
}
```

Comment: Thank you, by the way I tried it there is no need to call .Save(); since it's creation

Comment: I needed these three usings to get this code to work: 
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing;